# My browser is updated but still I see a warning that current version does not support TLS 1.2 on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate, tls

I am using the latest version of Chrome and when I open the following website 
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html 
(This website is used to evaluate Protocol Support, Logjam Vulnerability, FREAK Vulnerability, POODLE Vulnerability, Protocol Features etc)

I want to test if my browser is compatible enough to open secured websites by visiting the above link but it shows me a warning that my browser does not support TLS 1.2 and that I need to upgrade.

But my browser is up to date.

Any ideas why this might be happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [No TLS 1.2 (SHA-2) Support on chrome 12](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90392) was reproted Jul 25 2011 and was marked fixed on Jun 27 2013: "Chrome 29 will enable TLS 1.2 by default". [My understanding of this article is that TLS 1.2 Support may has some quirks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/06/19/windows-7-adds-support-for-tlsv1-1-and-tlsv1-2/)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome [prior to version 29] doesn't support TLS 1.2, only Internet Explorer does so. Chrome supports 1.1 and Firefox and Safari support 1.0. IETF considers 1.1 as well as 1.0 to be obsolete, but regardless, this is the case.

Source: [TLS Versions and Browser Compatability](https://sites.google.com/site/tlsssloverview/ssl-v-tls/tls-versions-and-browser-compatability)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now. Thanks a lot. But I am not able to open up a secured website that has TLS 1.1 enabled on server side. Since Chrome has that protocol supported shouldn't it be able to open that website at least. I mean is there some other reason this might be happening.

Comment: I'm going to have to withdraw my earlier answer, since apparently TLS v1.2 IS supported by all major browsers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Web_browsers

So the issue lies somewhere else.

Comment: You could try to see through the Chrome settings and see if it's just disabled. Quick note, do you happen to use BitDefender?

Comment: Chrome does support TLS 1.2 The article is quite old and I actually managed to set it up. The website does open now.